# FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo performances

Tags: c#, performance, winapi

I have to use the function "FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo" on a lot of files at a high invocation frequency.

I experienced very very slow performances doing that!

Do anybody know why?

Many thanks!

Comment: That's pretty bizarre, executables don't change their version number that quickly.  Or ever, really.  Sounds like a job for FileSystemWatcher instead.

Comment: Disk access is slow. Why are you suprised that reading lots and lots and lots of scattered clusters turns out to be slow?

Comment: What is the background of that requirement?

Comment: How slow? Please give some numbers.

Comment: It's rather pointless to say that something is slow without giving code, without giving timings, and without giving expectations of what performance is expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function does not do much except interpret some bits from the PE file. It is probably not CPU intensive but disk-seek-intensive because if must read once or twice from each file you analyze.

This means that all you can do is optimize IO patterns. If you're on an SSD or any other device with hardware parallelism, use multiple threads to execute the function on all work items in parallel. If it's a magnetic disk, there's not a lot you can do.